# Cassandra AuthenticationException when one node is down

Tags: authentication, cassandra

Trying to setup password authentication in cassandra. When both nodes are up, cqlsh is able to login succesfully with user/password. However when one node is down cqlsh spits the following exception

```
AuthenticationException(why='org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM')
```

Cassandra Configurations:

authenticator: **PasswordAuthenticator**

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {
'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
'replication_factor': '2'
};
```

have tried with

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {
'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
'DC1': '2'
};
```

as well but it doesn't work. Another dataspace is being replicated just fine so the issue is with configurations for authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok so I created a super user other than 'cassandra' and was able to login. Probably cassandra doesn't allow to login with the default user when consistency level is not achieved(one node down).

Keyspace is replicated.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {
'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
'DC1': '2'
};
```

Ran nodetool repair and voila I can login when the other node is down as well.

Comment: Apparently it's not just when one node is down. As far as I can see, if ANY node is down and you're trying to log in with the default user, cqlsh will fail with the "QUORUM" error.